# Trying to get the last TABLE element (xpath)

Tags: javascript, xpath

I've got an html document and am trying to access the last TABLE element.

If I do the following - I get the correct snapshot length of 5.

`var headings = document.evaluate( ".//table[@class='blue']",document.body, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);`

Looking at the HTML page structure - 2 of the TABLES captured by the xpath are nested

TABLE
TABLE
  TABLE
  TABLE
TABLE      << this is what I'm interested in.

There are only 5 tables in the document with class='blue'

I'd like access to the last one - so I did:

`var headings = document.evaluate( ".//table[@class='blue'][last()]",document.body, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);`

It returns an unexpected length of 4 - I was expecting 1.

The last snapshot entry (idx=3) is the correct TABLE. With last() in, it seems to be skipping 1 table that's hidden.

How can I just get the last TABLE element?

Looking at the html document - there are 5 tables with class='blue' and two of them are nested

```
TABLE
TABLE
  TABLE
  TABLE
TABLE   <<-- I'm interested in this one
```

I tried

`var headings = document.evaluate( ".//table[@class='blue' and position() = last()]",document.body, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,null);`

and it returned a length of 3 - the middle three tables.

Comment: I believe it's `[position() = last()]`...

Comment: No that wasn't it. I think it's to do with the double square brackets. Is there a way to do logical and inside the first bracket?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the correct answer is

`"(.//table[@class='blue'])[last()]"`

needed the perens around `table`.

Is there any inefficiencies?

Better way to do the same?

Comment: Not a better way, but another option : `//table[@class='blue'][count(./preceding::table[@class='blue']])=count(table[@class='blue'])-1]`